# How to disable UIM "cooked mode"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

A user on my machine has an xfce4-terminal open.  This automatically starts a special character (think Chinese character) input method like UIM/SCIM.  That means, some ordinary characters are not entered directly into the shell, but instead queued for compositing (a key sequence may be replaced by a character not bound to a single key on the keyboard)- similiar to "cooked mode" input.  Since I do not need this annoying feature I wish to disable it:

**How do I disable UIM / non-keyboard direct input which is started by xfce4-terminal?**

`ps` says that `xfce4-terminal` starts `gnome-pty-helper` which in turn starts `/usr/lib/uim/uim-helper-server`.  My strong suspicion is that these are the culprits.  However, I cannot find any configuration files of these programs.  There is no file with the string "uim" in `~/.config`.  When I kill these input helper processes they are restarted automatically.

The user in question is not logged in via `gdm` or similar and does not have a separate X session, just this terminal window.

Comment: To get rid of them just this once, I think you can simply kill the UIM process, but beware that it might make the terminal unusable. To prevent them from starting, dig through environment variables that contain `IM` in their name or `uim` in their value, probably something like `GTK_IM_MODULE=uim`.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks.  The processes are restarted when I kill them (thought I had written that).  `env | grep -i ui` is empty.  Do you know what config files there may be?  (Of course I could try `cp -p /bin/true /uim/uim-helper-server` or something but it ought to be possible without that!)

Comment: From dim memory of when I last had similar problems, it was one of the libraries used by the program (xfce4-terminal), that started the IM helper process based on the value of one of the `*_IM_MODULE` variables (`X_IM_MODULE`, `GTK_IM_MODULE`, `QT_IM_MODULE`, … depending on the widget stack).